# Cocoa 32 bit and 64 bit binaries within app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, unix

My latest Mac App got rejected from the Mac App Store.

Basically it didn't work due to a self contained unix executable contained within the app.
I have included a binary within my app before, that app is in the Mac App Store but this unix binary is giving me troubles.

I have compiled 2 different versions of this binary on a i386 machine and the other on x86_64 machine. 
Using "file appname", I get for the 64 bit binary

> Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

and the 32 bit binary

> Mach-O executable i386

At runtime I try to execute the correct binary but I noticed doesn't seem to matter? Which binary I use, I can execute the x86_64 on and i386 machine and things work fine.

My application build settings are what comes with the default project (standard 32/64 bit intel).

The question is should I attempt to run the 32 bit binary when I the app is running on an i386 machine?
And why does my x86_64 binary work when I run this on a i386 machine?

Thanks, John.

Comment: How do you know the ‘i386 machine’ is i386 only? Also, why not a universal build?

Comment: I checked the i386 machine using "uname -a" which said i386 but I didnt know it could be running other architectures?

Comment: IIRC uname tells the kernel architecture, and 64-bit capable machines can boot a 32-bit kernel — this is mandatory in some Core 2 Duo machines that are 64-bit capable but the EFI isn’t. Run `sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable` — it shows 1 in case the machine is 64-bit capable and 0 otherwise.

Comment: `uname -a` will tell you whether the kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit, but it doesn't tell you about the CPU. The first several generations of Intel Macs that used 64-bit capable Core 2 processors shipped with 32-bit firmware, so the kernel has to be 32-bit, but userspace code can be 64-bit.

Comment: ahh, I see both machines say they are 64 bit capable. Its core-solo that is really old I assume could be giving me grief.

Comment: The original Core - i.e. *not* Core 2 - is 32-bit only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you not building your Unix tool as a universal binary?  Then the operating system will pick the correct version of the binary to run based on the machine's architecture.

**EDIT** - to add my comment as part of the proper answer.

You need to build the i386 and x86_64 binaries. Obviously, you need to build the exe and all the dependencies for both architectures. It may be enough to use the gcc flag -arch=i386 everywhere for the i386 architecture. Then you can use [lipo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) to combine the two binaries.

Comment: I suppose the simple answer is that I am not 100% sure how to. The tool is httrack and I have had a hard time getting the dependancies correct for this. I used this command [./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-zlib=/opt/local --enable-shared=no] the big thing I needed was that the binary not rely on other libs, so that it would run fully self contained.  How do I compile with i386 and x86_64?

Comment: You need to build the i386 and x86_64 binaries.  Obviously, you need to build the exe and all the dependencies for both architectures.  It may be enough to use the gcc flag `-arch=i386` everywhere for the i386 architecture.  Then you can use lipo to combine the two binaries.

Comment: I have just done that now, figured out lipo. "lipo httrack64 httrack32 -create -output httrackx" I think that will work so the executed binary will work without me trying to figure out which binary to execute within my cocoa app. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I have combined with Lipo. I am now going to resubmit to the app store and figure out what happened. Cheers, John.

Comment: @John: best of luck.  I just hope that was the rejection issue and not your inclusion of a binary under GPL.

Answer (score 2):

You are making things too complicated. You do not need a 64bit machine to build the 64bit binary, nor is it a problem to build the 32bit binary on the 64bit machine.

GCC and thus XCode easilly supports building of either 32bit universal, or 32/64bit Universal images so you don't have to worry at all about running the correct one.

Comment: XCode is creating the universal app for me, that is working fine.  I have included a unix-binary in my app that I have managed to compile from the command line. I have both a x86_64 and i386 version of this app but for some reason I have had issues getting this binary to work correctly on different architectures. Now have used lipo to combine them, thanks for you help.